# Change Java_Home Path in windows 10 without admin rights

Tags: java, spring-boot, maven, windows-10, git-bash

I have a *windows 10* laptop and I donot have admin rights. But there is already jdk 11 installed in my laptop with **JAVA_HOME** set in system variables. So one of my project does not compile with java 11 and I needed to install jdk 8 and I followed [this instructions](https://zemian.github.io/2018/03/23/install-windows-jdk-without-admin-rights/) and installed it.

I have set the **JAVA_HOME** again in the user variables. But when I tried to see the version using `java --version` I could only see the `jdk 11` that is set in system variables and I cannot see the `jdk 8` that I installed in the `C:/Users` directory. So how can I set/change the **JAVA_HOME** for my maven project to build in git bash and run the spring boot app.

**EDIT:**

***note***: I have also added the %JAVA_HOME%\bin to User variables Path.

Comment: You should add `%JAVA_HOME%\bin` to the user environment variable `PATH`.

Comment: I have already added that to the path

Answer (score -1):

As suggested, you can add to the PATH the `%JAVA_HOME%\bin`
https://maven.apache.org/install.html

Then using the ff. command, verify what JDK version your maven using

```
mvn -v
```

you should see something like this

[image: output screenshot]